# Building my own direction controller for 3-Phase sensored BLDC motor

Tags: arduino, mosfet, brushless-dc-motor, mosfet-driver

I am new to this domain so I have researched and found a prototype circuit. I am working on two motors:

1. 60 V, 800 W sensor BLDC motor
2. 36 V, 300 W sensor BLDC motor

I am looking for the right type of MOSFET and MOSFET driver. I am using an Arduino.

Comment: Is the example circuit you are following using p channel and n channel mosfets? Or just N channel mosfets?

Comment: They are just n-channel mosfets

Comment: Probably the best way to find the part you need is to go to the website digikey.com then in the search bar search for "MOSFET" and select "Transistors - FETs, MOSFETs - Single". Then you can customize exactly what you need. You can specify you need N channel MOSFETs and the max Drain to Source voltage has to be above 60 volts because your motor will require 60 volts.

Comment: You can also search "BLDC motor driver" in the search bar on digikey.com and it will give you different ICs that you can use. I am also making my own 3 phase electric speed controller currently and the parts I am using are a FAN7392N for my MOSFET driver, and an IRL40SC228 for my N-Channel MOSFETs. The motor I am using is a 50V 3500W motor though.